# Storing a list of currently edited files

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, struts-1

I must program a webapp that let's a user create and modify files.

Those files will be stored on the server. There are mainly two pages in this app : the first one lists the files the user is allowed to see. The user click on one of the item of this list : this let him go to the second page, where he can edit the file.

My problem is simple : I want to make sure that you cannot see, in the first page (list of every files) files that are currently being modified by another user (in the second page). The application is in Java EE using Struts 1 (I didn't decide about that).

I've considered using a static List, for instance, that let me register every files that are currently opened ; I would put a file in the list when a user click and edit the file. In an ideal world, when the user save his work or goes back to the list, I would then remove the file from the list. However:

1. This is not thread-safe
2. What if a user just closed the browser?

What way would you proceed to solve this problem?

Comment: If you haven't decided on using Struts 1 yet, don't use Struts 1--there's no reason to deliberately choose such an old technology. Use Struts 2, Spring-MVC, Grails, whatever.

Comment: If I had the choice, I would have of course taken a newer technology. Unfortunately, I'm forced to work with this. (And half the software I'm trying to improve is made of COBOL - to - Java autogenerated classes...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thread safety is easily added to that scenario. The more important issue is that a file needs to be unlocked automatically once a user editing a file goes away, closes his browser, burns down his house or whatever. An automatic release of the file, coupled with some kind of refresh command sent from the browser periodically could solve this problem.

Comment: "Thread safety is easily added to that scenario" - with a simple synchronize ? The idea of the refresh command is nice but wouldn't it mean that I would have to use asynchronous javascript (which, foolish as it is, I'm not allowed to use...).

Comment: Yes, you “only” need to synchronize accesses on the list, and check if the file is already in the list before adding it to prevent multiple users from editing the file at the same time. If a user tries to edit a file that another user started editing just a millisecond ago you’d have to show that user an error message even though the file was available when he clicked it.

Answer (score 0):

okey you can keep a table on the database contains the current open files for editing and use javascript in the second page to keep tracking if the user is editing the page i.e writing from keyboard and if not wait for some time then make a call to the server to remove the file and redirect the user to the first page  i hope this will help u ?